# HTML table to excel - PHP

Tags: php, html, excel

I am creating a report in Table format. 
This report is displayed on the browser.
I want to provide a download report in excel format link so that the report can be available in excel file also.
How can I do this

Comment: I came across some solution regarding your question.So could you try this http://wsnippets.com/export-html-table-data-excel-sheet-using-jquery

Answer (score 16):

Either you can use [CSV functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) or [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) Or there is even a better and a simple solution. Just put the Table HTML in a file and save it as XLS file but that might give variety of problems.

Comment: Putting the HTML into a text file and saving it as an .XLS is a fantastic solution to this problem that works great for simple tables.

Comment: It works, but in Excel 2010 (and possibly future versions) it pops up a warning saying "the file *may* be corrupted, are you sure you want to open it?".  The default answer is no, so it may confuse some users.

Comment: FYI, PHPExcel has been archived since 2019, and it is not maintained since 2015, the developers are redirecting PHPExcel users to PHPSpreadsheet instead. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Answer (score 14):

```
<?php
$file="test.xls";
$test="<table border=1><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: i am using ms excel 2007 . and there cells are not visible when i export file. it gives message before open that "the file you are trying to open has different format than specified by the extension"

Answer (score 1):

I've used a service called [DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/) which does awesome html to excel conversion. It also does html to pdf conversion.

If there are better solutions out there as far as retaining the look of your original html and css in Excel, I haven't seen them.