# export javascript table to excel or to console table

Tags: javascript, excel, console

I have build a table:

```
function insertTable(elementName, text, textColor, backgroundColor, relativeOffsetArea, fatherBC, scrollArea, offsetArea, clientArea) {
    this.elementName = elementName;
    this.text = text;
    this.textColor = textColor;
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    this.relativeOffsetArea = relativeOffsetArea;
    this.fatherBC = fatherBC;
    this.scrollArea = scrollArea;
    this.offsetArea = offsetArea;
    this.clientArea = clientArea;
}
```

And i'm adding to this table data during the running process..

but when I'm viewing the filled table in console log with this code:

```
  console.table(consoleResult,["elementName", "text", "textColor", "backgroundColor", "relativeOffsetArea", "fatherBC", "scrollArea",
               "offsetArea", "clientArea"]);
```

the maximum number of the lines is 1000.
does console table is limited to length of 1000 ?
Do you familiar with another way (maybe excel) to export this table ?

Comment: You are going to have to add some more info. What are you referring to? Is this in the browser? which one? or is it using the JS MS Excel API? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to export this table to excel file... the browser or the referent are not  relevant to this task.

Comment: console.table only works in some browser versions. If you want this data in excel just loop it to a server script and download it as an xls with and html table in it. ( its a bit hacky but excel will happily open an html table saved as an xls file)

Answer (score 0):

console.table only works in some browser versions. If you want this data in excel just loop it to a server script and download it as an xls with and html table in it. ( its a bit hacky but excel will happily open an html table saved as an xls file)

in php heres an example:
[HTML table to excel - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437745/html-table-to-excel-php)